# "flying-sphinx start" results in Faraday::Error::ParsingError (for internal server error response)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, thinking-sphinx

I am getting below error while reindex or restart the flying sphinix on heroku

```
Running `flying-sphinx start` attached to terminal... up, run.8515/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at
'<!DOCTYPE html> (Faraday::Error::ParsingError)
<html>
  <head>
  <title>We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
  div.dialog {
  width: 25em;
  padding: 0 4em;
  margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-bottom-color: #999;
 }
 h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
 </style>
  </head>

<body>
<!-- This file lives in public/500.html -->
 <div class="dialog">
<h1>We're sorry, but something went wrong.</h1>
<p>We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I have restart the thinking sphnix using command heroku run flying-sphinx restart

Comment: What versions of Rails, Thinking Sphinx and Flying Sphinx are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a search daemon already running.  You need to kill it first with thinking sphinx and then retry your flying sphinx reindex or restart.

Here's an answer that will show you how: [Thinking Sphinx after deployment - ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (unknown local index 'user_core' in search request):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886364/thinking-sphinx-after-deployment-thinkingsphinxsphinxerror-unknown-local-in)